# String or binary data would be truncated when updating datatable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to update customer info. I use this code to load 5 fields:

```
  cust_cn.Open()
    Dim cust_da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [customers] where [custID]=" & txtCustPhone.Text, cust_cn)

    cust_da.Fill(cust_datatable)

    txtCustPhone.Text = cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("custID")
    txtCustFirstName.Text = cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("first")
    txtCustLastName.Text = cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("last")
    txtCustAddress.Text = cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("address")
    txtCustZip.Text = cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("zip")
```

and this works fine. When I try to modify one of the fields (change zip code on an existing customer)
with this code:

```
  If cust_datatable.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("custID") = txtCustPhone.Text
        cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("first") = txtCustFirstName.Text
        cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("last") = txtCustLastName
        cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("address") = txtCustAddress.Text
        cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("zip") = txtCustZip.Text
        'cust_datatable.Rows(custrecord)("custID") = txtCustPhone.Text
        'cust_datatable.Rows(custrecord)("first") = txtCustFirstName.Text
        'cust_datatable.Rows(custrecord)("last") = txtCustLastName.Text
        'cust_datatable.Rows(custrecord)("address") = txtCustAddress.Text
        'cust_datatable.Rows(custrecord)("zip") = txtCustZip.Text

        cust_DA.Update(cust_datatable)
    End If
```

I get the error: "String or binary data would be truncated"
I originally tried to update using the commented section, but it was only modifying the first record in the database.
Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the data types of the columns that you are trying to update?

Comment: The first line of your commented code is trying to set custID to the phone number.

Comment: custID actually  IS the phone#. datatypes are: custID(pk) nchar(10)... first (nchar15)... last (nchar20)... address (nvarchar50).... zip (nchar5)

Comment: There could be white spaces. Use `TRIM()` function like `cust_datatable.Rows(0).Item("zip") = txtCustZip.Text.Trim()`

Comment: Ugh! How do your users change their phone number? Is custID a varchar? Do you have a maxlength on your textbox?

Comment: update: txtcustlast was missing  the ".text" property. I fixed that and got "violating primary key" error. I commented out the first field"custID" and now I am always updating the first record in the DB :(

Comment: It seems like modifying  a field makes an update to the first record. How can I tell my sub to remember which record it is modifying?

Comment: Are you changing the data in text boxes at all after loading them?

Comment: if I pull up a record and make no changes and trigger the update, I get "violation of Primary Key constraint".

Comment: You are always updating the first row because of the Rows(0) in your code).  Do you have an indicator somewhere that designates the current record you are one?  Change the (0) to that.